# Dell Synaptics Touchpad Issues

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad

Running Ubuntu 12.04 on a fresh install but nothing I've found seems to work. What has got me even more stumped is this:

```
user@ABCD:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver
```

I've gone to the Dell site and tried to install their drivers, no luck. Checked the Ubuntu SC, installed, no luck. Researched on here, no luck.

Please someone have a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Install or reinstall (if already installed) the device driver:

Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 and copy paste following command and press Enter.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Or reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: this may have worked, but it still hasn't recognized the touchpad in xinput. Will reboot and update.